# Is this possible with Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with two combine chart types, line and column. I would like, as in the image below, to have my column chart at the bottom and my line chart a bit higher up and the line chart label to start hihger up as well.
I want something like:

```
yAxis: labels{y: -100}
```

My problem with this is that this only moves the labels, not the chart data.

My try so far can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/32r7rctt/2/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set 'height' and 'top' properties of the yAxis. 
 Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mtvy24rj/1/

```
yAxis: [{
      height: '70%',
      top: '0%'
    }, {
        title: {
        text: null
      },
        height: '30%',
      top: '70%',
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
    }],
```